# how to use user @param inside query

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a query in sql server:

```
select  tblDivingClub.number,tblDivingClub.name,tblDivingClub.country,
count(distinct     tblDiving.diving_number) as number_of_divings
from tblDivingClub
inner join tblDiving on tblDivingClub.number = tblDiving.diving_club
WHERE tblDiving.date_of_diving >@param
group by  tblDivingClub.number,tblDivingClub.name,tblDivingClub.country
having count(distinct  tblDiving.diving_number)>1200
```

When I run the query, I want the user to enter the date @param.
How can I do that? How do I declare the @param and use it?

Ty

Comment: Besides that this is way too broad and lacks of code - You did not mention how you execute the query, not even with what programming language or framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic method in SQL would be to use a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].YourStoredProcedure
@Param DATETIME2

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  tblDivingClub.number ,
        tblDivingClub.name ,
        tblDivingClub.country ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT tblDiving.diving_number) AS number_of_divings
FROM    tblDivingClub
        INNER JOIN tblDiving ON tblDivingClub.number = tblDiving.diving_club
WHERE   tblDiving.date_of_diving > @param
GROUP BY tblDivingClub.number ,
        tblDivingClub.name ,
        tblDivingClub.country
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT tblDiving.diving_number) > 1200

END
```

Then call the procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.YourStoredProcedure @Param = '2014-08-08'
```

Comment: Ty!
Why calling the procedure like that:
EXEC dbo.YourStoredProcedure @Param = '2014-08-08'? why 2014-08-08?

Comment: That was just an example - you can use any date you want or pass a variable via your outside coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it and then specify that the parameter must equal, greater to, or less than the value being selected in the SELECT statement.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Procedure
@iDate SMALLDATETIME

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  tblDivingClub.number ,
        tblDivingClub.name ,
        tblDivingClub.country ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT tblDiving.diving_number) AS number_of_divings
FROM    tblDivingClub
        INNER JOIN tblDiving ON tblDivingClub.number = tblDiving.diving_club
WHERE   @iDate=tblDivingClub.dateofdiving,
GROUP BY tblDivingClub.number ,
        tblDivingClub.name ,
        tblDivingClub.country
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT tblDiving.diving_number) > 1200

END
```

Of course you need a date column in the table that corresponds to it so it can be compared?

Then execute it of course:

```
EXEC dbo.Procedure @iDate = '2014-08-08'
```

And the date being entered should match the format of the column it's compared with.

The answer above describes it perfectly.